# How to convert http request to Python?

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I need your help.

I am looking to communicate with a REST API containing sensor data at port number 3.
I have a Json (POST) request that works perfectly executed on a REST client like Insomnia.

My request :

```
{ "header": { "portNumber": 3 }, "data": { "index": 40 } }
```

[Picture of my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdVO.png)

However I am unable to make it work on Python and to recover data from my sensor.

My Python code :

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://192.168.1.100/iolink/sickv1' # Address of the OctoPrint Server
header = {'portNumber': '3', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} #Basic request's header
data = {'index': 40}


def get_sensor_measure():

r = requests.post(url + '/readPort', headers=header, data=data)

print(r.content)
print(r.status_code)
```

I get the error:

```
b'{"header":{"status":1,"message":"Parsing Failed"}}'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Write it out and properly format it in your question instead!

Comment: @BcK Unfortunately, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `'portNumber': '3'` in `data` not in `header`:

```
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = {'header': {'portNumber': '3'}, 'data': {'index': 40}}
```

And also as [Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59752564/2255764) stated in his answer you need to changes `data` to `json`:

```
r = requests.post(url + '/readPort', headers=header, json=data)
```

Comment: @LouisErard Please accept the answer if your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are using the wrong field to pass your payload. It isn't really obvious, but the `requests` package expects JSON-type payload to be sent with the `json` field, not the `data` field, i.e.:

```
r = requests.post(url + '/readPort', headers=header, json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few changes (Bold), it works. Thanks

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.100/iolink/sickv1' # Address of the OctoPrint Server
    header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} #Basic request's header
    **data = {'header': {'portNumber': 3}, 'data': {'index': 40}}**

    def get_sensor_measure():

        r = requests.post(url + '/readPort', headers=header, json=data)

        print(r.content)
        print(r.status_code)
```